# Shakespeare's vasty deep: was "vasty" a recognised variant of "vast" at the time?

Tags: william-shakespeare, wording-choice, word-coinage, henry-iv-part-i

From Shakespeare's *Henry IV Part 1*, [Act III Scene 1](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/1henryiv/1henryiv.3.1.html):

> GLENDOWER: I can call spirits from the vasty deep.
>
> HOTSPUR:    Why, so can I, or so can any man;
> But will they come when you do call for them?

The phrase "vasty deep" is still somewhat used, and "vasty" appears in [modern dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vasty), but *only* in reference to this one passage of Shakespeare. I'd guess that "vasty" might have been used instead of "vast" for [reasons of rhythm](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12470/17), but **was it a recognised word at the time, or was Shakespeare exercising some poetic license to invent a new variant of "vast"?**

Comment: The OED isn't aware of any use before Shakespeare. But that doesn't really mean much; Shakespeare is given credit for the first use of lots of words that he probably didn't invent (although I suspect he invented this one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are five occurrences of "vasty" in Shakespeare's plays:

- *1 Henry IV*, III.1.50: "I can call spirits from the vasty deep"
- *Henry V*, Prologue: "Can this cockpit hold / The vasty fields of France?"
- *Henry V*, II.2.123: "He might return to vasty Tartar back"
- *Henry V*, II.4.105: "the poor souls for whom this hungry war / Opens his vasty jaws"
- *The Merry Wives of Windsor*, II.7.41: "the vasty wilds / Of wide Arabia"

*A Shakespeare Glossary* by C. T. Onions (revised by Robert D. Eagleson, 1986) defines "vasty" as "Vast, immense, boundless".
(Shakespeare also used the term "vastidity", meaning "immensity", in *Measure for Measure*.)

Gary Taylor's edition of *Henry V* (The Oxford Shakespeare, 1982) notes,

> According to *OED*, Shakespeare invented this word. He never uses it in prose; three of its five appearances are in this play.

The fact that Shakespeare only used it in verse suggests why he invented (or used) "vasty" instead of "vast": to fit the iambic metre of his lines.